# Oracle : PLS-00103 occur on procedure with condition

Tags: oracle, if-statement, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

When I tried to compile this procedure:

```
PROCEDURE GET_NUMBER_PROPOSED_TRADES(p_client_id NUMBER, p_curr_id NUMBER, p_cursor  OUT sys_refcursor)
IS
BEGIN  
  OPEN p_cursor FOR
      IF (p_client_id = 0 AND p_curr_id = 0)
      THEN
        SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT NVL(id,0)) AS "Proposed_Trade_Number"  FROM proposed_trade;
      ELSE
        SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT NVL(id,0)) AS "Proposed_Trade_Number"  FROM proposed_trade WHERE client_id = p_client_id AND ccy_id = p_curr_id;
      END IF;
END GET_NUMBER_PROPOSED_TRADES;
```

this error occurred:

> Error(9,11): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null select with          continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date       pipe
>
> Error(18,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PROCEDURE" when expecting one of the following:     end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static    member constructor map The symbol "static" was substituted for "PROCEDURE" to continue.
>
> Error(25,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PROCEDURE" when expecting one of the following:     end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static    member constructor map The symbol "static" was substituted for "PROCEDURE" to continue.

But the thing is, if I just remove IF condition, I can compile it easily, so this kind of a new for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest an `if` condition inside a cursor declaration, it's just not valid syntax. One way around this would be to have a single query, and use the `where` clause conditions to get the same logic you were trying to get from the `if`:

```
OPEN p_cursor FOR
    SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT NVL(id,0)) AS "Proposed_Trade_Number"  
    FROM   proposed_trade 
    WHERE  (p_client_id = 0 AND p_curr_id = 0) OR 
           (client_id = p_client_id AND ccy_id = p_curr_id);
```

Comment: Thanks, I would try another similar case to use `where` clause